# Changing the background color of the window title in GTK3

Tags: gtk3, color-management

I would like the title of the active window to be white on blue (to clarify: somewhat like Microsoft Windows XP). Here is my `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
.titlebar .title {
color: #000066;
}

.header-bar {
background-image: none;
background-color: #A9F5A9;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

The header bar becomes green as intended, but the window title stays the same.  I have also tried with:

```
.titlebar .title {
color: #000066;
}
```